# How to add right click to tree view ODOO?

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-8, right-click

I wanna add a right **click option** to my **tree view** for showing a contextuel menu ( Update , delete ... )

[I wanna replace this menu with the menu in the second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIbAH.png)

[second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8aNl.png)

Thank you.

Comment: Are you taking about to add the  new action on more menu... ??